# Can a MEMS accelerometer sensor be used as a shock sensor?

Tags: iot

I am trying to make an IOT project- SMART DOOR where I have used a serve motor and NodeMcu and for adding further functionality I have been thinking of adding a theft detection feature where whenever a large force is applied on the lock an alarm starts beeping and for that I don't have a shock sensor but I do have MEMS accelerometer sensor(MPU6050 Accelerometer and Gyroscope).
So can I use it to add this functionality?
If yes, can I get a little guide on what configuration and sensitivity I should use?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Please don't scream at us. I removed the capslock from the title for you

Comment: haha! Thank you :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure you can. A "shock" is merely a large amount of acceleration over a short period of time.

You would probably want to set the MPU6050 to its least sensitive setting (±16g), and you might even be able to make use of the "tap" function whereby the MPU6050 itself looks for a sudden short sharp shock to trigger an interrupt (though that may be a little too sensitive for your needs, I don't know).

Comment: Thank you so much!